# Resharper c++: toggle a single line comment for a selected block

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

The shortcuts related to comments are:

`ctrl+k ctrl+u/c` to un/comment selection.

`ctrl+shift+/` or `ctrl+k ctrl+/` to toggle a comment.

When a block is selected, it will always use `/*...*/`, which I can do myself. I'd like it to toggle a line comment `//` for each block line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReSharper has two [comment actions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Coding_Assistance__Comment_Uncomment_Code.html), "Comment with Line Comment" and "Comment with Block Comment". Use "Comment with Line Comment" (Ctrl+Alt+/) in your case.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+/ didn't do anything, but I set a new shortcut to the action your pointed out. Thanks.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+/ is the default keybinding in the Visual Studio scheme. If it was not set, could be that your keyboard bindings were garbled (might happen if you use multiple input languages to a VS bug). Try resetting keyboard shortcuts first in VS options, then in R# options.

Comment: Maybe, but it was easier just to define any shortcut that I wanted, which was easy once you pointed out the menu operation in resharper.